# How to disable the title time range for the month view?

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

Currently, FC displays the title of the month view with the current and the next month separated by a dash : "janvier — février 2015" (in french).

What I want is to display only the current month : "janvier 2015".
I searched in the doc and the examples but I was not able to find a solution ...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I've not seen this happen. Can you please provide a code sample that replicates the issue?

Comment: I fixed the problem, I was using moment.js 1.8.3, I have upgraded it to the 1.9.0 and now it works as expected :)

Comment: OK. You can post your fix/answer and then "accept" it as the answer so this question can be closed out... helpful if anyone has the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, I was using moment.js 1.8.3, I have upgraded it to the 1.9.0 and now it works as expected :)